# How to open a WPF window, and run a Method, only once the view has loaded and is visible

Tags: c#, wpf, stylet

I'm using MVVM ViewModel first with Stylet.
I have a method that takes a long time to run called `Run` in my `Simulation` class and I want to open window with a status bar which has a viewModel called `StatusViewModel`.

The result I am getting is a blank window opens, the method `Run` runs, and only when this method has finished does the content of the window display the Status Bar.

How do I get the method `Run` to only run once the view of the status bar window is loaded?

I am currently opening the status widow and running the `Run` method as follows:

```
public void RunSimulation()
    {
        this.windowManager.ShowWindow(StatusViewModel);
        simulations.Run(StatusViewModel);
    }
```

I've also tried the following in the `StatusViewModel` but I get the same result:

```
protected override void OnViewLoaded()
    {
        simulations.Run(this);
    }
```

I feel that I need a protected override that only fires once the view has finished loading, rather than load being called as it does with `OnViewLoaded`.

What other ways are there to achieve what I want?

Comment: What you need is to run the `Run` method asynchronously : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Comment: I've got that working as intended now, many thanks